# Ввод/вывод массива с заданным количеством элементов, на языке C

Tags: c

Здравствуйте, написал программу для ввода/вывода массива с заданным количеством элементов, но не знаю как сделать так, чтобы количество элементов вводил пользователь.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
void input(int a[5])
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
}

void output(int a[5])
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    clrscr();
    int a[5];
    printf("Print 5 elem mass: ");
    input(a);
    printf("Printed mass: ");
    output(a);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С помощью динамического массива. Что-то типа

```
int* input(int* num)
{
    int i,n;
    printf("Input number of elements: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int * a = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("a[%d] = ",i);
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    *num = n;
    return a;
}

void output(int *a, int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("a[%d] = %d\n",i, a[i]);
    }
}

int main() {
    int n;
    int * a = input(&n);
    printf("Printed mass: ");
    output(a,n);
    free(a);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: не работает строчка 
        int * a = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
        cannot convert void* to int *

Comment: Значит, вы написали неправду, что на языке C. Это в C++ вот такое пишет, на C компилирует без проблем. Или компилируйте, как C, или добавьте `(int*)` прямо перед `malloc`... Только если это был бы с самого начала C++, то код был бы другим...

Comment: int *a;
    printf("Input number of elements: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    a =(int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int)); 
Только что добавил сам и заработало) спасибо, а пишу я на Си, но стандарта 92 года

Comment: Ну, если ответ устраивает - помечайте как принятый...

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь, пометил